# how to save data from json in sqlite in android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I'm new in Android programming and I want to find how to store data from json in sqlite for android.I didn't find any useful examples of it in internet,that's why I'm asking here.If you show me a simple example of it I will be very happy.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a model class that has the properties of your JSON model.

Create a constructor in your model that accepts an `org.json.JSONObject` (Search the android developers reference).

In the constructor, read the values of the `JSONObject` to your properties with for example the methods `String optString()` and `int optInt()`.

You can also use [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) for Android to save the object to SQLite. You can find working examples here:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/android-examples

You will need to import the ormlite-core and ormlite-android .jar libraries in your Android project.

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/ormlite/files/releases/com/j256/ormlite/

ORMlite works fast and has convenient access methods.  I have used it multiple times in my projects.

Comment: can you explain how to use this