# Store JSON object response from server in to sqlite database

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save data from Json object to Database (SQLite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288500/save-data-from-json-object-to-database-sqlite)

I am making an android app that gets data from server, save it and use those data later when there is no connectivity. How to save JSON object in SQLite database, I have no clue.
Please give me some example to understand it better. I really appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: why you saving into sqlite instead of mysql because JSON, PHP and ANDROID works perfect together.

Answer (score 1):

Transform the json to string and just insert it to the database.
When you need it , retrieve it from database and use :

```
data = new JSONObject(str).getJSONObject("data");
```

str = json string retrieved from database

Answer (score 0):

try out this

[how to save data from json in sqlite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563118/how-to-save-data-from-json-in-sqlite-in-android)

[How to store JSON in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375382/how-to-store-json-in-sqlite)

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9766/android-optimize-json-insertion-to-sqlite-insert-on-duplicate-key-ignore

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

I am assuming that now you are getting the data from JSON object, and the issue is saving it.

1. See the type of the fields and the numbers of fields that you want to store in SQLITE DB.
2. Store the values in JSON objects in their corresponding data types.
3. Suppose JSON object User has 4 fields

   Name - String
   Password - String or char[]
   Age  - int
   City - String
4. Retrive the values as below.

   `jsonObject.getString("name");`

   `jsonObject.getString("password");`

   `jsonObject.getInt("age");`

   `jsonObject.getString("city");`

Answer (score 0):

is perfect to save in mysql using JSON, PHP and ANDROID because they work perfect together rather than trying in sqlite