# Parse nested Json object and store in database in Android

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I just tried to get values that are stored in my JSON file and save it into sqlite database:

This is my JSON file:

```
{
  "list": {
    "meta": {
      "count": 132, 
      "start": 0, 
      "type": "resource-list"
    }, 
    "resources": [
      {
        "resource": {
          "classname": "Quote", 
          "fields": {
            "date": "2017-03-16", 
            "price": 3.6720000000000002, 
            "type": "currency", 
            "symbol": "AED=X"
          }
        }
      }, 
      {
        "resource": {
          "classname": "Quote", 
          "fields": {
            "date": "2017-03-16", 
            "price": 65.075000000000003, 
            "type": "currency", 
            "symbol": "AFN=X"
          }
        }
      }, 
      {
.............
}
............
```

I have tried like this but getting exception :

```
JSONObject mainObj = null;
try {
    mainObj = new JSONObject(JSON);
    JSONObject getSth = mainObj.getJSONObject("list");
    if(mainObj != null){
        JSONArray list = getSth.getJSONArray("resources");
        if(list != null){
            for(int i = 0; i < list.length();i++){
                JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
                if(elem != null){
                    JSONObject prods = elem.getJSONObject("fields");
                    Object level = prods.get("type");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+level.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I was getting exception : no values in fields...

And pls give some suggestions that storing these values in Database table(matrotable) of(row fields) name, prize, symbol and type, I may try by making String Array and retrieving and storing the values for sqlite, is there any other easy options...
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `fields` objects are inside `resource` object so do

```
  for(int i = 0; i < list.length();i++){
                JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
                if(elem != null){
                    JSONObject prods = elem.getJSONObject("resource")
                                           .getJSONObject("fields");

                    Object level = prods.get("type");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+level.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

> ```
> "resources": [                      // resources list
>   {                                 // object i
>     "resource": {                   // fields are inside "resource" object 
>       "classname": "Quote", 
>       "fields": {
>         "date": "2017-03-16", 
>         "price": 3.6720000000000002, 
>         "type": "currency", 
>         "symbol": "AED=X"
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ```

Comment: yes thnx, i need to store to sqlite and then retrieve later, how can i achieve that easily, my go is by adding these fields to string array and retieveing it ? any other suggestions.

Comment: @Learner then you should take a look into `GSON` then you will be able to create a pojo list , try the [GSON docs link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/4158/gson#t=201703181903413153608)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `resource` JOSNObject parsing...

```
 for(int i = 0; i < list.length();i++){
                JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject resource = elem.getJSONObject("resource");
                if(resource != null){
                    JSONObject prods = resource.getJSONObject("fields");
                    Object level = prods.get("type");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+level.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: yes thnx, i need to store to sqlite and then retrieve later, how can i achieve that easily, my go is by adding these fields to string array and retieveing it ? any other suggestions.

Comment: take a look at this: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288500/save-data-from-json-object-to-database-sqlite)  create a model class with getters and setters...or another option to use GSON with Pojo..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you to use the simplest and easiest way to parse a json response to avoid this kind of issues:

1- generate your model classes by using this tool: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ download and add the generated classes to your model package.

2- add this dependency to your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

3- Call this method to parse your response:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ResponseModel responseModel = gson.fromJson(json, ResponseModel.class);
```